# Why is the Suez canal empty?

Tags: sea-travel, egypt

Apart from a single vessel (you can probably guess which), the Suez canal is empty. There are plenty of vessels queuing.

[image: Suez canal with only Ever Given left][image: There are plenty of vessels waiting]

Why? Is it closed for travel?

Comment: Wait, I thought the you-can-guess-which-vessel had meanwhile been removed?

Comment: Whatever it was - meanwhile several vessels have entered (six southward, four northward)  / are in the process of entering the canal (at least half a dozen approaching the southward entry at 7-8 kn)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen No, the Suez canal operator doesn't allow further passage through the rest of the canal, because they are seeking damages for lost revenue (the ship has been removed from one canal portion and is now located in the middle of the canal in the Great Bitter Lake).

Comment: I would suppose that it was necessary to keep ship traffic out while the banks of the canal were repaired and the channel was dredged to the proper depth.  @dunni insurance and liability claims take months to years to resolve.  There is little reason to stop operating the canal while pursuing other parties for compensation.

Comment: It’s worth remembering that the canal operates using a convoy system. There’s one southbound and one northbound convoys each day, starting at 3:30 and 4:00 respectively. If you look at the wrong time, the convoys may have already reached their destination (about 12 to 15 hours later) and the next ones not started yet. Also the deadline to join a convoy is 23:00. https://www.suezcanal.gov.eg/English/Navigation/Pages/NavigationSystem.aspx At what time did you capture the traffic in your pictures?

Comment: The BBC indicates that the backup is 'cleared', whatever that means...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about travel in the scope defined in the [help].

Comment: @phoog I didn't mean that they closed the whole canal, i meant that they don't allow the Ever Given to proceed further because of liability claims.

Comment: @dunni that makes more sense.  Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Indeed, if you look right now, there are 13 ships headed north in the northern part of the canal (and a few more that have already completed their journey seemingly without incident) and 8 headed south in the southern part of the canal. You just happened to pick the moment when nobody was moving.

Answer (score 5):

@jcaron seems to be on point.

The [canal operates using a convoy system](https://suezcanal.gov.eg/English/Navigation/Pages/NavigationSystem.aspx): A southbound staring at 03:30 and a northbound starting at 04:00.

So at 03:30 the canal is likely to be empty, and looking at the canal later confirms you can travel through it.